# `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant User (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

**spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

**я запускаю команды :**

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

**выпадает ошибка :**

```
E:/work/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'

        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block
 in load_spec_files'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'

        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_
spec_files'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
  #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#new__config_option_to_disable_rspeccore_monkey_patching
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # This setting enables warnings. It's recommended, but in some cases may
  # be too noisy due to issues in dependencies.
  config.warnings = true

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

**помогите решить**

Comment: А выложите spec_helper. У вас не загружаются классы приложения.

Comment: MAXOPKA я добавил spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

В **spec-rails-3** вместо **require 'spec_helper'** используется **require 'rails_helper'**
  Подробнее - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в начало хелпера строку

`require 'rspec/rails'`

Comment: Я добавил строку в начало spec_helper.rb и получил очень много ошибок 
``<class:ERB>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB::ENCODING_FLAG (NameError)`
это не весь текст ошибки